# Search function for Table in website using PHP, mySQL, HTML

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table of data in my website and I want to add search functions which could be based on criteria such as Name, type and date because the data in table are about events.

Here is my table code:

```
<?php
$user="admin";
  $pass="whatever";
  $host="localhost";
  $db_name="eventregisteration";

  $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
      if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
      $sqlget="SELECT * FROM eventform";
      $sqldata=mysqli_query($con,$sqlget)
      or die("Error Getting Data");
      echo "<table border=2 bordercolor=#440000 cellpadding=2 bgcolor=#DDDDDD width=100%>";
      echo "<tr bgcolor=#555555 style=font-size:18px><th>Event Code</th><th>Event Name</th><th>Event Type</th><th>Event Level</th><th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th><th>Point</th><th>Picture</th><th>Video</th><th>Description</th></tr>";



      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<tr align=center><td>";
          echo $row['event_code'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['event_name'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['event_type'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['event_level'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['start_date'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['end_date'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['points'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['pic'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['video'];
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $row['description'];
          echo "</td></tr>";


      }

       echo "</table>";
      ?>
```

I need a dropdown box with type, date , name and a textbox, I don't know how to connect these to each other so if the user wants to search by name they choose name and if they want to search by date a calendar pops for them.

Comment: why u need this code? This is for displaying results only right

Comment: actually i need to display the picture and video by using link but i dont know how to do that ,, do you suggest any other way?

Comment: are u storing only file names in database? and r u working on localhost. let me know.

Comment: im storing file path on database ,yes im using XAMPP

Comment: can you provide a sample entry for both picture and video.

Comment: i dont get it sorry , when i submit picture my picture will be stored in local folder ,, rather than database ,, im only saving the file path in database

Comment: Can you give one sample value for picture and video fields from database. Just to check whether you are storing it as absolute or relative path. And also where are you actually storing the picture/videos, I mean in which folder in the project these are stored ?

Comment: $pic= ($_FILES['pic']); 
  $temp_pic=($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
  $pic_name=($_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
  $temp_video=($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"]);
  $video_name=($_FILES["video"]["name"]);
  $uploads_dir_pic = "eventpic/".$pic_name;
  $uploads_dir_video="videos/".$video_name;                               
            
  move_uploaded_file($temp_pic,$uploads_dir_pic);
   $path_pic=($uploads_dir_pic);
   }
   move_uploaded_file($temp_video,$uploads_dir_video);
   $path_video=($uploads_dir_video);

Comment: $uploads_dir_pic = "eventpic/".$pic_name

Comment: $path_pic=($uploads_dir_pic);

Comment: so is it absolute or relative?

Comment: also make sure that the permission of the image folder should be set to read-write-execute. This you can do by right clicking on the folder and setting permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path according to the location of the page in which you are calling the picture/video. Suppose that your folder structure is like

**Project Folder**

*eventpic

   videos

file.php

file1.php*

and suppose that you are calling the image in file.php file. Then, you have to give path as
`<img src="<?php echo $row['pic'];?>">`

or

`<img src="localhost/workspace/project/<?php echo $row['pic'];?>">`

Now suppose that your files are stored in other folder say **view**, now your project folder structure will be

*eventpic

   videos

view*

In this case, the pictures/videos are outside your file's folder. So you have to specify path as

`<img src="../<?php echo $row['pic'];?>">`

or

`<img src="localhost/workspace/project/<?php echo $row['pic'];?>">`

../ will move outside the current directory.

Comment: echo "<img src=xampp/htdocs/greenstudio/eventpic>"; echo $row['pic'];
it shows unloaded pic and the pic name with path ,,